# How to call tab bar view controller from simple view controller which is embedded in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

How can I call **TabbarViewControllers** connected viewController from simple **UIViewController** where  simple **UIViewController** is embedded in **UINavigationController**. I want same Push and Pop effect which UINavigationController provide when moving one to other viewController. After digging in google I find out that pushing tab bar view controller inside navigation stack is not a good way to structure app. I tried creating custom transaction animation but it's not same like UINavigation transaction effect. Please give some suggestion or solution. Thanks!!

Comment: Mean you need to open UITabbarController from normal view controller, right?

Comment: yes @Nirmalsinh.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set UITabbarController to window's rootViewController.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
_tabObj = (TabbarViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarViewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = _tabObj;
```

Check above code.

Comment: present modally don't give animation like UINavigationController push animation

Answer (score 0):

as [Nirmalsinh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013229/nirmalsinh)'s answer, you could set view controller that conform `UITabBarControllerDelegate` as your `self.window.rootViewController`, then should have `UITabBarController` inside it.

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController
```

then you can each of tab's navigation and view controller

```
let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
let firstNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
// other setter

tabBarController.viewControllers = [
    firstNavigationController
]
```

then inside `FirstViewController`, you can call

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
```